# How come System.IO.File is returning false when the file does exist?

Tags: c#

I'm using `System.IO.File.Exists` to check if a file exists. However, it's returning false for a file that I know exists. The code is the following:

```
Assert.IsTrue(System.IO.File.Exists(@"\ImportRepositoryTest\Version2.xml"));
```

How come `System.IO.File` is returning false when the file does exist?

Comment: Your code assumes that the current drive is correct, and that `\ImportRepositoryTest` exists in the root of that drive. Are you sure those assumptions are true?

Comment: Are you sure that the relative path is correct?

Comment: Yes, before that line I do data = Framework.Import.data.Loadv2(TestContext.TestDeploymentDir + @"\ImportRepositoryTest\Version2.xml");. This gives an error if the file doesn't exist (I tried it with a non-existing file).

Comment: Try full path first, then also check your permissions and finally check the application's working directory. You say you use "TestContext.TestDeploymentDir +" and it works, but then you don't use it in your Exists statement. That implies you are sure that your working directory is TestContext.TestDeploymentDir.

Comment: @LeSnip3R wow that was me being really stupid... Putting TestContext.TestDeploymentDir in front of it made it work, thanks! You can put that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: I had this type of issue recently. Have you tried making a folder named ImportRepositoryTest (and adding version2.xml to it) in your bin\debug folder ? I take it you use visual studio. and if yes , why not try setting your directory path  where you check the file exists to Environment.Current.Directory + "@\ImportRepositoryTest\Version2.xml"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
Assert.IsTrue(System.IO.File.Exists(Path.Combine(TestContext.TestDeploymentDir,  @"\ImportRepositoryTest\Version2.xml")));
```

Answer (score 2):

Change it to `Assert.IsTrue(System.IO.File.Exists(@".\ImportRepositoryTest\Version2.xml"));` (with a ".") and double check to see if you marked your file as "copy always".